# Powershell v3 Remoting from C# using Enter-PSsession

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to use Enter-PSsession from C# to enable and use Powershell remoting to run commands remotely. 
Here is a code

```
Runspace remoteRunspace = Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
remoteRunspace.Open();
powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Enter-PSSession");
command.AddParameter("ComputerName", "remotehostname");
command.AddParameter("Credential", vmmCredential);
powershell.Commands = command;
powershell.Invoke();
```

I get CmdletInvocationException. 
Here is the details for the same.

> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException was unhandled
>   Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
>   Source=System.Management.Automation
>   WasThrownFromThrowStatement=false
>   StackTrace:
>          at > System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecute(Array input, Hashtable errorResults)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Execute(Array input)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Execute()
>          at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>          at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
>     InnerException: System.Management.Automation.PSNotImplementedException
>          Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
>          Source=System.Management.Automation
>          StackTrace:
>   at > System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost.GetIHostSupportsInteractiveSession()
>   at > 
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost.PushRunspace(Runspace runspace)
>               at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand.ProcessRecord()
>               at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
>               at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
>          InnerException:

If I try the Enter-PSsession directly from powershell I am able to start a remote session with no issues... Can anyone advice as to what is wrong in C# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I was not able to get Enter-PSSession cmdlet from C# code but below is the code which I was able to use to do PS remoting using C#...

```
int iRemotePort = 5985;
string strShellURI = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
string strAppName = @"/wsman";
AuthenticationMechanism auth = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;

WSManConnectionInfo ci = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    false,
    sRemote,
    iRemotePort,
    strAppName,
    strShellURI,
    creds);
ci.AuthenticationMechanism = auth;

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ci);
runspace.Open();

PowerShell psh = PowerShell.Create();
psh.Runspace = runspace;
```

You can now use psh to run the commands remotely.